# Confusion about meaning of sentences in Economist

Tags: meaning

I am confused about the parts in bold while reading Economist.

> And the **feeble** recovery is **petering out**.
>
> Their prescription for a weak economy is **a** large **slug** of austerity.

Why do we use the article *a* instead of *the* since it's talking about a specific slug? What does *slug* here mean anyway?

Comment: Not to be confused with [large slug](http://www.naturephoto-cz.com/photos/krasensky/large-red-slug-0214.jpg)

Comment: @mplungjan I've never seen anything like that before! What an appalling photograph. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it's not talking about a specific slug, actually. *Slug* here means a strong drink—"a slug of whiskey," for example. It's being used in a figurative sense in the sentence you quoted, of course.

*Feeble* means "lacking strength, weak, infirm" (*Oxford English Dictionary*). *Petering out* means "dwindling away to nothing" ([The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/peter-out.html)).

To sum up: the economic recovery is lacking strength, and in fact is dwindling away to nothing. The only way to truly fix the economy is with an unpleasant but necessary period of austerity, in which we forgo luxuries and make do with the bare necessities of life.